# Unit testing custom input and output format

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, hadoop

I have been trying to figure out if one can develop unit tests for custom input and output format implementations. I have found this example with MRunit :https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MRUNIT/MRUnit+Tutorial. It looks like MRUnit is good for testing mapper and reducer only. I also saw this post :[How to do unit testing of custom RecordReader and InputFormat classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371953/how-to-do-unit-testing-of-custom-recordreader-and-inputformat-classes). But looks like this particular example depends on HDFS paths?

Ideally, what I need is to be able to test custom input and output format implementation as junit test case from IDE environment (Eclipse). There is no single/multi-node cluster setup available. How can we do unit test under the circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty much do the same thing which has been specified in the thread : [How to do unit testing of custom RecordReader and InputFormat classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371953/how-to-do-unit-testing-of-custom-recordreader-and-inputformat-classes)

The following setting actually makes the HDFS code to run in local pseudo mode  :

```
conf.set("fs.default.name", "file:///");
```

Comment: Who starts/provides the local pseudo mode? Can you run it from eclipse as a junit test?

Comment: Yes the code provided in the link will run in local mode with no modifications (On windows you will need Cygwin) When you want to run on the cluster you will have to set the fs.default.name to your Namenode or you can remove this setting altogether & the code will run in local mode & on cluster you will have to add core-site.xml to your classpath.