# Trouble unit testing custom input format

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, hadoop

I am new to hadoop world. I developed a custom input format and reader for my application. I am having trouble running unit test. I followed this post to develop my unit test : [How to do unit testing of custom RecordReader and InputFormat classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371953/how-to-do-unit-testing-of-custom-recordreader-and-inputformat-classes). My unit test code looks exactly like the one in post except the InputFormat class :

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration(false);
    conf.set("fs.default.name", "file:///");
    File testFile = new File("/tmp/testfile");
    Path path = new Path(testFile.getAbsoluteFile().toURI());
    FileSplit split = new FileSplit(path, 0, testFile.length(), null);
    MyFileInputFormat inputFormat =     ReflectionUtils.newInstance(MyFileInputFormat.class, conf);
    TaskAttemptContext context = new TaskAttemptContextImpl(conf, new TaskAttemptID());
    try {
        RecordReader reader = inputFormat.createRecordReader(split, context);
        reader.initialize(split, context);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

When I try to run this test using "mvn test", I am getting the following error :

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration$DeprecationDelta
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ConfigUtil.addDeprecatedKeys(ConfigUtil.java:54)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.util.ConfigUtil.loadResources(ConfigUtil.java:42)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.(JobConf.java:119)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
            at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:810)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:80)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:64)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
```

Can anyone help me understand how to fix this?

Comment: This is not an answer but why you do not create you custom RecordReader using a your RecordReader constructor. When I developed my own InputFormat I just created my own RecordReader using my own factory method not the InputFormat.createRecordReader factory